# Accessing JavaScript variable in different <script> block

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Below is a basic snippet of code that uses HTML5 geolocation to get the user's latitude and longitude coordinates. It then stores the values in userLat and userLng.

For testing purposes, I included a basic document.getElementById().innerHTML snippet. If I move that block of code to the original  block it works fine. However, if I move it to it's own  block (as shown), no response is given to the variable. How can I globally assign the 2 variables so I can access their values outside of the first  tag?

Thanks.

```
    <script>

    var userLat;
    var userLng;

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(storeLocation);
        }
    }
    function storeLocation(position) {
        window.userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        window.userLng = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    window.onload = getLocation;
    </script>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("userLocationInfo").innerHTML="Latitude: " + userLat + "<br>Longitude: " + userLng;
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the script below executes first rather than the function getLocation, as this function is called when window is completely loaded.

you are trying to use values of userLat and usrLng before they got assinged any values

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it that way, you can assign them as properties of `window`: in other words, as `window.userLat` and `window.userLng`. Or if you want to cut down on names in the namespace, you could make a `window.userCoordinates` object, and then define `window.userCoordinates.latitude` and `window.userCoordinates.longitude` properties.

Answer (score -1):

try declare the value of the variable without the 'window' statement
        userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        userLng = position.coords.longitude;

Comment: Actually, window is the global object when running JavaScript in browsers, so it wouldn't make a difference (appart from the fact that userLat and userLng are being declared as variables in that scope). The problem, as @shadow points out, is that they are being referred to before being assigned a value.

Comment: Sorry about taht, i never have to use window for declare a variable.